# AAR / JAR not get generated with Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7

Tags: android, kotlin, aar, android-studio-3.0

So, the title pretty much sums up my problem. Anyone know how to fix it? Last time I build apk, it work fine on AS 2.X, but, I'm now developing with Kotlin so, I have to use AS 3.0.

I use AS 3.0 Canary 7 (This project is a fresh project)

This is my dummy class in my library (Stored in "domain".library.mylibrary)

```
class Test {
    fun hello(): String {
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

And this is my (mylibrary) gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version" //Declared in project level gradle: ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
}
```

My gradlew.bat clean build --info log: https://pastebin.com/bfTZ5s4e

Comment: Where is your class stored. Post the whole path (relative to your project)

Comment: Also run the command `./gradlew clean build --info` and append the log please.

Comment: @guenhter ok wait

Comment: @MosesAprico Also replace `compile` to `implementation` in dependencies

Comment: @guenhter gradlew.bat is automatically closed when finished. How to retain it?

Comment: @MosesAprico you should run it via `cmd` (I guess you use Windows). So open `cmd` and navigate to your project. Than call it with `gradlew.bat clean build --info`. The output will remain in your `cmd`-session

Comment: @guenhter done. please check my edit.

Comment: @guenhter weird, the aar is now shows up. i tried to clean project > make project from AS to test it once again, but the output doesn't re-shows up. If I choose rebuild project, it's now shows up again. Is this an intended behavior?

Comment: I just ran into this with the release version of AS3.0. I can build the AAR from the CLI using gradlew but for the life of me can't figure out how to build it from the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio does not generate a jar by default, but rather an **AAR** file. If you want to get a **jar output**, you need to implement `apply plugin: 'maven-publish'` on top of your `mylibrary/gradle.build` file and read the following document: [Chapter 36. Maven Publishing (new)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Another note, is that I would suggest you **not to use ProGuard directly** on your release artifact, but rather provide a consumer ProGuard file and let the users of your library to handle that task, otherwise they will have a hard time referencing obfuscated code. Read my answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48059964/2759296)

While the **build** task may generate an output, it is known that the `assemble` task (or `assembleRelease`) is the one that will generate your **aar** output.

Try running the following command:

```
./gradlew clean assembleRelease
```

and check the output in `/mylibrary/build/outputs/apk/release/` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Still only see an aar file with studio 3.1.1